# CRM 2011 - Weird ERROR importing the customization - An optionset with the specified name already exists. Please specify a unique name

Tags: import, customization, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, importerror

We have 3 environments at our client :
* DEV
* UAT
* PROD

They were all "CRM 4.0".  The client decided to switch to CRM 2011! So we first upgraded the "DEV"  and did all the modifications they've asked!  We exported all the customizations to put it on the "UAT"-server.

We've migrated the UAT to "CRM 2011" and if I want to import the customizations of the "DEV", it gives me an error on all the "System" entities : **An optionset with the specified name already exists. Please specify a unique name.**

When I export for ex. account from the "UAT" and from the "DEV" and compare them in "ExamDiff" everything seems to be correct.  All the optionsets are the same and they all have the same values. The only thing that changed is there are new fields and new Views. But there again, we didn't delete any attribute (field) on the CRM.

We need to make the "UAT"-server work before we can put everything on the "PROD". The deadline is next week and I can't seem to find why the CRM 2011 does that.  So it's really Urgent...

Does any of you have encoutered this problem? Even for the entities we didn't change a thing it gives me that error..

Comment: If it is really that urgent and a show stopper, than SO is possibly the wrong place to ask. In this case I would open a support incident with the CRM support at Microsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved the problem! It was the rollup 4/5 that caused the problem.  I hope Microsoft solves this in rollup 7!

So I did the following :
1. Re-installed the server
2. Re-installed CRM
3. Imported the "CRM"-DB
4. Installed the rollup 3
5. Customizations were imported with **NO** errors...

We opened a Case at Microsoft, because a CRM with no Rollups is not a good way of working I guess!